# PyQt6 connecting link click to QDesktopServices.openUrl causes type error

Tags: pyqt6

```py
self.lbl_supporting_text.linkActivated.connect(
            lambda link: QDesktopServices.openUrl(QUrl(link))
        )
```

```
Error: Argument of type "(link: Any) -> bool" cannot be assigned to parameter "slot" of type "PYQT_SLOT" in function "connect"
  Type "(link: Any) -> bool" cannot be assigned to type "PYQT_SLOT"
    Type "(link: Any) -> bool" cannot be assigned to type "(...) -> None"
      Function return type "bool" is incompatible with type "None"
        Type cannot be assigned to type "None"
    "function" is incompatible with "pyqtBoundSignal"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

Is there any way to fix this error or maybe open a link in an external user's browser some other way?

Comment: That seems an error of the IDE, not from python. Does the program work properly?

Comment: @musicamante Yep, the program work just fine. It's the problem of wrong typing on PyQt stubs side maybe

Comment: It may be, verify if you are using the latest version of the stubs and check [their page](https://github.com/python-qt-tools/PyQt5-stubs). Remember that IDE warnings related to completion and type hints are **not** program errors.

Comment: @musicamante You sent me a link for PyQt5 stubs, however, I use PyQt6 v6.5.0 is there for PyQt6, or maybe stub gen command, I can't remember it

Comment: Just go to the project maintainer page and you'll see the Qt6 stubs repositories